# Find time in array, if not found, select previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, time

I have an array with times, where the first number is the hour and the second number is the minute. There's also a time interval (in minutes), start time, and end time. So for example:

```
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];
var endTime = [16, 20];
```

It will start with `startTime` and increase by `interval` 40 minutes.

```
[10, 40]
[11, 20]
[12, 0]
[12, 40]
[13, 20]
[14, 0]
[14, 40]
...
```

How can I make it so that it finds the time that is right before `var time`? (Please note that `startTime`, `endTime`, `interval`, and `time` will all be dynamic.

In this example, the final `result` should be `[14, 0]`.

Another example, if the `time` is `[13, 20]`, the final `result` should be `[12, 40]`.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? The question is clear, but could you show us your solution? Currently this sounds like "please code this for me"

Comment: The internal seems to be 40 minutes, not 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use Dates and Times as `DATE`

In the following you must make sure :

```
startTime <= endTime
```

And also

```
startTime <= time <= endTime
```

```js
$(function(){
    let
        time = [14, 35],
        interval = 45, // in minutes
        startTime = [10, 40],
        endTime = [16, 20],
        markTime = true;

    time = new Date('2000-01-01 ' + time[0] + ':' + time[1] + ':00');
    startTime = new Date('2000-01-01 ' + startTime[0] + ':' + startTime[1] + ':00');
    endTime = new Date('2000-01-01 ' + endTime[0] + ':' + endTime[1] + ':00');

    while (startTime <= endTime) {
        let nextTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + interval*60000);

        if (nextTime > time && markTime) {
            $("#divTimes").append('<b>' + startTime.getHours() + ':' + startTime.getMinutes() + ' <<</b><br/>');
            markTime = false;
        } else {
            $("#divTimes").append(startTime.getHours() + ':' + startTime.getMinutes() + '<br/>');
        }


        startTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + interval*60000)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divTimes">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var time = [14, 35],
    interval = 45, // in minutes
    startTime = [10, 40],
    endTime = [16, 20];

var a=startTime[0]*60+startTime[0],
    out=a,
    findTime=time[0]*60+time[0],
    endMins=endTime[0]*60+endTime[0];

while(a<findTime && a<endMins){
    out=a;
    a+=interval;
}

console.log(Math.floor(out/60),out%60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a recursive approach that may work for you. Note, we are using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on the arguments the method `getTimeBefore()` receives.

```js
const getTimeBefore = ([startH, startM], [endH, endM], ival, [checkH, checkM]) =>
{
    let [newH, newM] = [startH + Math.floor((startM + ival) / 60), (startM + ival) % 60];

    if (newH >= checkH && newM >= checkM)
        return [startH, startM];
    else if (newH >= endH && newM >= endM)
        return "Not Found" // Or anything you need;
    else
        return getTimeBefore([newH, newM], [endH, endM], ival, [checkH, checkM]);    
}

console.log("Time before 14:35 is:", getTimeBefore([10,40], [16,20], 40, [14,35]));
console.log("Time before 13:20 is:", getTimeBefore([10,40], [16,20], 40, [13,20]));
console.log("Time before 19:05 is:", getTimeBefore([10,40], [16,20], 40, [19,05]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```